# Get value from a class in swift -> missing argument for parameter "userName" in call

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am a beginner swifter and I'am facing a problem in my first application ... 
I need to get a value from the class `Person` which is the `userName` value. I am going to display it in a label in the current view controller.

Here is what I have done so far.

This is the viewController where I am working in:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var Name = Person().userName()
    label.text = Name 
}
```

And this is the class `Person`

```
class Person {
    var cellName = "empty" 
    init(cellName : String) {
        self.cellName = cellName
        super.init()
    }

    func userName() -> String {
        var uname = cellName
        return uname
    }
}
```

The `userName()` function will return the `cellName`, which will be initialised in another class.

The problem is in the `viewDidLoad()` function, I got an error which says "missing argument for parameter 'cellName' in call"
I have no idea what the solution of this problem is. I searched for similar errors but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Name = Person().userName()
```

Here, you're calling the initializer that you defined in your `Person` class, like this: `init(cellName : String)`. However, you can clearly see that with these empty braces `()`, your call is indeed lacking the `cellName` argument.

Two solutions: either provide the `cellName` argument, or create another initializer that accepts no argument. Here's how it could look like:

```
init() {
    super.init()
}

convenience init(cellName : String){
    self.cellName = cellName
    self.init()
}
```

**EDIT**: As a sidenote, from what I can see right now of your `Person` class, it could be a lot simpler. The `userName` doesn't have to be a `func` and could be a simple `var`. It is currently returning another existing `var` which is also public, so from what I can see right now, it is useless. In fact, you could actually rewrite the class with almost the same features using a single line of code, like this: `struct Person { var userName = "empty" }`. That's it :)